# I want to export an ip address into multiple components in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

e.g.
http://192.162.27.989/CRB/api/building/

This is an API where i want to export into different components as it is being used several times. So whenever IP changes I only have to make the changes into 1 file not several times.
How can I reuse this IP again and again in different files by just defining something.

Comment: You can define a `const` in 1 file and import in all others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `api-endpoints.ts` or what ever you want or suitable for you

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'http://192.162.27.989/'; 

export const API_BUILDING1_ENDPOINT = API_BASE_URL + 'CRB/api/building1';

export const API_BUILDING2_ENDPOINT = API_BASE_URL + 'CRB/api/building2';
```

and then where you want to use this endpoint just import it.

```
import { API_BUILDING1_ENDPOINT API_BUILDING2_ENDPOINT } from 'somepath/api-endpoints';
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a ts file `config.ts`

### config.ts

```
export const BASEURL = '#';

export const DATAURLS = Object.freeze({
  IP:  BASEURL  + 'http://192.162.27.989/CRB/api/building/',
  IP2: BASEURL  + 'http://192.163.27.989/CRB/api/building/'
});
```

### .ts

```
// In your .ts file get it  by ->  `DATAURL.IP`
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In `environment.ts`, you can put your IP like this,

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseURL: http://192.162.27.989
};
```

And then import this variable by accessing the file `environment` and get the `BaseURL`.

In Component -

```js
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

// In class
private baseURL = environment.baseURL;

// Use like this
private yourApiEndpoint = baseURL + "/CRB/api/building/";
```

Answer (score -1):

Sachin has the right idea!  You can create a global constants file (e.g. global-constants.ts) like this:

export const AppGlobal = Object.freeze({
    IPAddress: '192.10.10.10',
    SupportPhoneNumber: '1-888-111-2222',
    CompanyFacebookUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/xxx',
    CompanyTwitterUrl: 'https://twitter.com/xxx',
    ....whatever else you want
});

And then in any component:

import { AppGlobal } from "../../shared/global-constants";  // put in the correct path

And reference your global with dot notation:

AppGlobal.IPAddress